# How to get member name from Interface that acts at Enum, Java

Tags: java, interface

Say I'm having the following Interface :

```
public interface NUMS {
  public static final int ZERO = 0;
  public static final int ONE = 1;
  public static final int TWO = 2;
 }
```

Then I have a function that returns int between 0-2.
Is there any option to get the member name that the number represents in the Interface?

ex:

functions return 1, I want to map it back to ONE, without using Map/Array.

Thanks!

Comment: why dont use enum for that purpose?

Comment: No, there is not possible besides using reflection or manually mapping all options.

Comment: Why not use an actual enum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, there is, using reflection:

```java
    String getConstantName(int value) {
        // use reflection to check all fields of NUMS
        for (Field f : NUMS.class.getFields()) {
            try {
                if (f.getInt(null) == value) {
                    return f.getName();
                }
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // ignore
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

But this is just for education purposes, please don't use approaches like this in real code. As other people suggested, just use an `enum`.

Comment: Thanks! I would definitely use Enum if I could, but Im just using an Interface that someone else wrote, cant change it.

Comment: @omrib40 then at least cache the results of reflection access in some kind of singleton string array or map.